# fetch and http does not get complete file. nativescript iOS

Tags: nativescript

Nativescript has two functions for making http requests fetch or the function http. I use those two functions to get the string of a site (response with the html) for IOS.

The problem is that it returns some of the response but it does not return all of the response for IOS. Meaning it only returns half the file for an http request.

For example:

```
http.getString("https://slashdot.org").then(function (html) {
        console.log(html)
    }), function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error)
    }
```

returns some of the response (html) but then it stops:

```
  var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.id = 'janrainAuthWidget';
        if (doc
```

Those are the last lines of the response before it returns at "if (doc". The last line should of been </html>. So http (and I also tried fetch) does not return the whole file.

I need to get a response for the whole file for my project to work.

What do I need to do so that http or fetch works? Is there some hidden timeout that gets activated. Or should I use CocoaPods and if I should use CocoaPods how?

Answer (score 0):

The same code at my side is returning the whole HTML content

result from the redirect page

```
    JS: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    JS: <html><head>
    JS: <title>302 Found</title>
    JS: </head><body>
    JS: <h1>Found</h1>
    JS: <p>The document has moved <a href="http://m.slashdot.org">here</a>.</p>
    JS: </body></html>
```

Even the redirect link is returing all the HTML needed so I guess it problem with your local setup or connectivity.

```
JS:     $(document).ready(function () {
JS:         function checkCloseAd(){
JS:             var adon = $('div.ad-on');
JS:             if(adon){
JS:                 var closead = adon.find('.close-ad');
JS:                 if(!closead || closead.length === 0){
JS:                     adon.prepend('<div class="close-ad"><span>Close Ad</span></div>');
JS:                 }
JS:             }
JS:         }
JS:         function footerFixer(){
JS:             var footer = $('#home .stage-center #footer');
JS:             if(footer.length){
JS:                 if(footer.length > 1){
JS:                     $('#home .stage-center #footer').eq(1).remove();
JS:                 }
JS:                 if(footerHtml != $(footer).html()) footerHtml = $(footer).html();
JS:             }else{
JS:                 $('#home .stage-center div').first().append('<div id="footer">'+footerHtml+'</div>');
JS:             }
JS:         }
JS:         $('#river_bottom').prepend('<div class="close-ad"><span>Close Ad</span></div>');
JS:         $('body').on('click','.close-ad', function(){
JS:             $(this).hide();
JS:             $('#river_bottom,#story_slot2').toggleClass('ad-on');
JS:         });
JS:         setInterval(checkCloseAd,1000);
JS:         setInterval(footerFixer,1000);
JS:     });
JS: </script>
JS:
JS: </body>
JS: </html>
```

Comment: Sorry I should of been more specific with my build. I'm getting that error for the IOS. Not the android, I also had a small problem with the Android version but I could fix it by setting the timeout parameter for the http function. However that still doesn't solve the problem for the iOS.